# behaviour of scanf while reading standard input

Tags: c, scanf

Will scanf skip white space characters before reading non-white space characters or any other data  with all the
the format specifiers like %d , %c , %s and all the other format specifiers.I am talking about the first occurrences of white space characters and not the subsequent ones.
for example,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main(void){
char str[N];
scanf("%s",str);
return 0;
}
```

In this case scanf will skip first occurrences of white space characters and read the next 
non-white space data and then if it again encounters white space characters , it will quit 
reading.

Comment: The code won't compile; `str` has an incomplete type.  You need to specify an array size.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i corrected that.

Comment: OP returns 13 months later to make a pointless edit... +1 for style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the `scanf()` format specifiers automatically skip leading white space.  White space includes newlines — see [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html).

The three exceptions are `%c`, scansets (`%[a-z]` etc), and `%n`.

Note that any white space in a `scanf()` format string is an explicit indication to skip optional white space.  That is, if there is white space, it will be skipped; if the next character is not white space, there is no white space to skip but no error either.

---

The POSIX page for `isspace()` misses out some of the information in the C standard:

> The standard white-space characters are the following: space (`' '`), form feed (`'\f'`), new-line
>   (`'\n'`), carriage return (`'\r'`), horizontal tab (`'\t'`), and vertical tab (`'\v'`). In the
>   "C" locale, `isspace` returns true only for the standard white-space characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want read the white space before the non-white space, you may need `fgets`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char n[10];
        fgets(n,10,stdin);
        printf("%s",n);
}
```

Run the program:

```
   343  5   <<--Input
   343  5   <<--Output
```